# How can I initiate scripts to run on my Mac from triggering events on my phone?

Tags: applescript

I would like to replace the mechanism I currently use to trigger scripts to run on my Mac. Currently, I use mostly [IFTTT](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ifttt/id660944635) applets that create text files in Dropbox. Then I attach folder actions to those folders that run a variety of scripts.

The triggers for running these scripts range from geofences, proximity to iBeacons, creation of google calendar events that match a search term, completion of tasks in the iOS Reminders app (which is currently broken in IFTTT/iOS 13), IFTTT button widgets, Siri & Siri Shortcuts, receipt of emails that match a search term, motion sensor triggers, etc., etc..

The problem is that relying on IFTTT to create the Dropbox file in a timely fashion is the weak point. Plus, Apple keeps putting up annoying roadblocks to automations that can be a pain.

I’ve been playing around a lot with web hooks and webhookrelay in Node Red on my Raspberry Pi, and that works great, but there are certain things I just need to run on my Mac.

I was thinking I could install node red on my Mac, but it just seems slightly heavy handed and I’d like to know what my options are before heading down that path. So I’d like to know what anyone else does to trigger scripts to run on their macs...?

Answer (score 1):

I use [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) in order to run AppleScript when certain events occur, and there is [EventScripts Mobile](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScriptsMobile.html) wich is a free companion application to *EventScripts* that let you trigger scripts on your Mac from your iPhone, iPod Touch, or iPad. You can find a demo on the link provided.

I never used it, but as *EvetScripts* is very reliable and quite easy to use, i'm gessing that *EventScripts Mobile* will do the work ! Also, you can try it for free.

(Note that EventScripts Mobile only works over Bonjour, and so is not suitable for triggering scripts on Macs not on your Bonjour network).

---

Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of *EventScripts*, just a satisfied user of the product.

Comment: That’s Cool. Definitely sounds useful, but sounds like it won’t work for geofence triggers. And also, my phone has chronic bonjour issues that I haven’t been able to figure out.