# Trigger an AppleScript each time I open a new Finder window

Tags: macos, applescript

Because of compatibility issues with the Accessibility API with Matlab, I cannot use traditional tiling window managers such as Amethyst or yabai. This is frustrating but I found an alternative at [Tiling Finder Windows in Mac OSX & macOS](https://techzei.com/how-to-tile-finder-windows-in-mac-osx/) which uses AppleScript to tile windows. I use it for Finder windows exclusively. I would like to have it perform every time I create a new finder window (so that it replication other TWM behaviour of automatically tile the Finder windows). I stumbled upon another similar question ([How can I initiate scripts to run on my Mac from triggering events on my phone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380614/how-can-i-initiate-scripts-to-run-on-my-mac-from-triggering-events-on-my-phone)).

I suspect this can be done but I am not sure how to implement this solution.